# assets rails 3.1 not load after precompile nginx + unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, production-environment

I am trying precompile assets in production env. But after precompile the app does not find the images files, javascripts files, css files...etc.

I run this command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

and I get this result:

```
/home/hyperrjas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/ruby /home/hyperrjas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
/home/hyperrjas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/ruby /home/hyperrjas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake assets:precompile:nondigest RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

then I try reload the page and I see this:

[image]

I'm using nginx + unicorn.

**Why the app not find the assets, images, css, javascript...**

### Edited**

I load my assets layout from **application.html.erb** with:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

I have in my nginx.conf this in server { }

```
location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
                          root ~/mydomain.com/current/public;
                          gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
                          expires max;
                          add_header  Cache-Control public;
                         }
```

Thank you

Comment: do you have "config.assets.digest = true" set in environments/production.rb?

Comment: Yes I have in `config/environments/production.rb` the next:  `# Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true`

Comment: can you see either from the html source or the server logs what the paths being requested are that are generating the 404s?

Comment: I can see in firebug in html tab this:  `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/application-757164eb38463ea8d323f05b3a3238ca.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/application-203db49c9ee856182159ad4bce51bf0e.js">`

Comment: How do you include the assets in your views? Are you directly referencing the assets or are you referencing the manifests?

Comment: so does this file exist in  your rails root?  public/assets/application-757164eb38463ea8d323f05b3a3238ca.css

Comment: one other thought - i have definitely had problems with aggressive browser caching and assets loading properly.  did you try a different browser, and/or explicitly clear your browser cache?

Comment: yeah I have tried load from different browsers and show the same result. @netmute I have edited the post with the response to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem was fixed :D:**

The error was in nginx.conf in:

```
location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
                         root ~/mydomain.com/current/public;
                         gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
                         expires max;
                         add_header  Cache-Control public;
                        }
```

The path to root to assets is bad, the correct form is:

```
 location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
                            root /home/hyperrjas/mydomain.com/current/public;
                            gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
                            expires max;
                            add_header  Cache-Control public;
                           }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First,

Can you check - Manifest Files and Directives
`app/assets/javascripts/application.js` it should be

```
// ...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

Check, below setting in config/environment/production.rb in your application
It should be true

> config.assets.compile = true

and if you want a digests for assets URLs, make below true if it is false.

```
config.assets.digest = true
```

Few reference links

http://mrjaba.posterous.com/rails-31-asset-pipeline-with-nginx-and-passen

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Sorry I have checked with this instruction and it does not work for me :(. the same result. I have edited post with config nginx for assets